# How to get direction(rtl/ltr) without know who has dir attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I wont to create component with different style according to the parent direction.

for example:

```
<!-- some tags with dir attribute -->
<my-component></my-component>
<!--close some tags with dir attribute -->
```

something equivalent to `:dir(ltr)`  that have chrome support ?

Update:
this is work, but how can i use it within another style?

```
[dir='rtl']  mat-header-cell {
  border-left: dashed;
}
[dir='ltr']  mat-header-cell {
  border-right: dashed;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:host-context`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context) selector if you are trying to adjust it from within your component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="with-border">Lorem</div>
  `,
  selector: 'my-component',
  styles: [`
    :host-context([dir='rtl']) .with-border {
      border-left: dashed;
    }
    :host-context([dir='rtl']) .with-border {
      border-right: dashed;
    }
  `]
})
export class MyComponent {}
```